# Why does this GPIO button click run twice if I remove the print statement?

Tags: gpio, python, python-3

I run this script when the Raspberry Pi boots. When a key is pressed (GPIO 19) the `interrupt` function gets called.

If I *remove* the `print("BUTTON PRESSED")` statement on line 10, the `interrupt` function seems to be called twice in a row for a single button press.

Any idea why this is the case?

```py
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import time
import subprocess

GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)

GPIO.setup(19, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_UP)

def interrupt(channel):
    print("BUTTON PRESSED")
    p = subprocess.Popen(['node', '/btn.js', str(channel)], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
    out = p.stdout.read()
    print(out)

GPIO.add_event_detect(19, GPIO.FALLING, callback=interrupt, bouncetime=1000)

try:
    while True:
        time.sleep(1)
except:  
    print("Exit GPIO Listener..")
finally
    GPIO.cleanup()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably [switch bounce](https://www.allaboutcircuits.com/technical-articles/switch-bounce-how-to-deal-with-it/) if it is a mechanical switch.

What you think of a single event may actually be multiple contacts and releases in a fraction of a second.

Comment: I would assume that the `bouncetime=1000` would have taken care of that?

Comment: So would I.  However bouncetime does not really debounce.  It simply ignores all signals for the bouncetime.

Answer (score 1):

All mechanical switches bounce - some e.g. reed switches are more prone to this. There are mechanical solutions used for high current power switches where arcing is an issue but these are inappropriate for logic circuits.

It is possible to minimise bounce - either by suppressing extraneous signals using a capacitor to limit rise time or by introducing delays in software but using changeover switch and bistable circuitry bounce can be absolutely prevented.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification ! I'm using the buttons from this board so I don't have too much control over the hardware as it eats up all my pins

https://www.waveshare.com/2.7inch-e-paper-hat.htm